# Issue with npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue when using npm start (used create-react-app). Anyone that can see what's wrong?

> Error notification in my terminal:
>       npm start
>       npm ERR! code ENOENT
>       npm ERR! syscall open
>       npm ERR! path C:\Users\charl\Desktop\IRONHACK\react-interview\package.json
>       npm ERR! errno -4058
>       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\charl\Desktop\IRONHACK\react-interview\package.json'
>       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

---

```
{
  "name": "particeep",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure you are executing `npm start` command in your project's directory

Comment: Does this path C:\Users\charl\Desktop\IRONHACK\react-interview\ has package.jsob

Answer (score 0):

try to delete package.json and write npm install

Answer (score 0):

1. npm cache clean -f
2. rm -rf node_modules
3. npm i

Comment: Clear Cache of cli and try to re run!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you used `npm create-react-app projectname` (with **npm**). This should **NOT** be done.

You want to use `npx create-react-app projectname` (with **npx**) when creating a new project.

I made the same mistake for my first project. Instead of messing around with the terminal, the simplest option I found was just copy the files you already have, delete the folder, and create a new react folder with **npx**

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `npm start` after going to the root folder of the app by entering `cd your_app_name`(app name which used with `npx creat-react-app` code in terminal)